# Accumulo table scanner failing silently in Java

Tags: java, accumulo

I am attempting to scan an entire Accumulo table with the Java API. I have verified that the meta info is all correct (credentials, ZooKeeper server, Accumlo Instance ID, table name). At this point I'm at a dead end so any suggestion is appreciated.

### Accumulo Version

1.6.2

### The code

Borrowed from [accumulo read client](https://github.com/acordova/accumulo-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/examples/simple/SimpleReadClient.java).

```
// scan the whole table
System.out.println("=== whole table ===");
Scanner tableScanner;
try {
  tableScanner = conn.createScanner("geomesa3_records", new Authorizations());
  // conn is of type Connector
  // Connector and Scanner are implemented in org.apache.accumulo.core.client
  // See links below for additional info
} catch (TableNotFoundException ex) {
  throw new RuntimeException("table not found - was SimpleIngestClient run?");
}
System.out.println("-------------------------------------");

for(Map.Entry<Key, Value> kv : tableScanner) { // seemingly freezes here
  System.out.println("----------------- new row ---------------");
  System.out.println(kv.getKey().getRow() + " "
      + kv.getKey().getColumnFamily() + " "
      + kv.getKey().getColumnQualifier() + ": "
      + new String(kv.getValue().get()));
}
tableScanner.close();
System.out.println("-------------------------------------");
System.out.println("=== end table ===");
```

### Intended results

```
=== whole table ===
-------------------------------------
----------------- new row ---------------
// table data
----------------- new row ---------------
// table data
----------------- new row ---------------
// table data
-------------------------------------
=== end table ===
```

### Actual results

```
=== whole table ===
-------------------------------------
```

### Relevant Accumulo Links

[`Scanner` API](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Scanner.html)

[`Connector` API used for `createScanner`](http://accumulo.apache.org/1.6/apidocs/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Connector.html#createScanner-java.lang.String-org.apache.accumulo.core.security.Authorizations-)

[`Scanner` interface](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=accumulo.git;a=blob;f=core/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/Scanner.java;h=31f985c541c13a9e9e2969c4e16509eb5400be54;hb=refs/heads/1.5)

Comment: Either your code won't compile or you should add your implementation of the class `Scanner`.

Comment: @Tom is that a question? If so, yes the code compiles (and executes) and `Scanner` is imported via `org.apache.accumulo.core.client.Scanner`

Comment: No, it was a statement. If you code compiles, then you're not using `java.util.Scanner` and therefore the `Scanner` code should be added to the question.

Comment: @Tom Sure, I'll add it to the question.

Comment: The API doesn't help here, we need the source code.

Comment: @Tom I added the link to the `Scanner`, which is apparently just an Interface. But even in the official Accumulo examples they use the `Scanner` without implementing it. For example: https://github.com/apache/accumulo/blob/master/examples/simple/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/examples/simple/client/ReadWriteExample.java

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you able to connect to the Accumulo database through the shell to query the data?

Comment: @MikeSlutsky Yes, `Scanner` seems to be an interface, so we need the implementation, which will be created using `conn.createScanner()` ... like [this one](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=accumulo.git;a=blob;f=core/src/main/java/org/apache/accumulo/core/client/impl/ScannerImpl.java).

Comment: @FuriousGeorge yes I can access the database and table via the shell and run scans from there. Tom I'm not sure if I know how to find that. My code is only importing the `Scanner` found in `org.apache.accumulo.core.client`, which is what I linked. I'm not sure how it could be implemented (yet it must be).

Comment: You can find that be following the `ZooKeeperInstance#getConnector()` call, which creates a `ConnectorImpl` instance and that class creates a `ScannerImpl` in `ConnectorImpl.createScanner()`, but at the end it doesn't help much. The `ScannerImpl` does too much to check its behavior without debugging. Do you know how to debug code? If so, then set BreakPoints in that class and to see where it stops/freezes.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I haven't done much Java debugging (mostly just C), but I guess that will have to be my next step here.

Comment: Try increasing the log4j verbosity to DEBUG and watch for messages from classes rooted beneath org.apache.accumulo.core.client. The fact that you can read the data in the shell but not a client is surprising. Did you log in as the same user in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to set a range on the scanner. To scan and entire table, just set the range like so:

```
scanner.setRange(new Range());
```

This range will match everything. Specifically, this range "goes from negative infinity to positive infinity". Basically it matches all possible Keys.

I use a similar strategy for a fetch all operation on one of my tables.

Also, just be aware that this sort of thing can definitely cause issues. If the table gets large, this could take a very long time to run. In my case I never expect the table to grow above a few hundred logical rows, so I consider it safe.